# Error when I import .css file from node-module

Tags: css, import, datepicker, react-hooks

Now I am trying to use DatePicker in React-hooks project.
But importing css from node-module make error.

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {Modal, Container, Row, Col, Button, } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { scheduleActions } from '../_actions';
import { Header } from '../_components/Header';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css"; //this make error.

......
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG9hs.png)

How can I fix it? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Please share all error messages in text form (not as screenshots!), along with your attempts to resolve the errors

Comment: Sorry for my laziness. But it's enough for fixing error. Aadesh gave me good answer then I fixed my error. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @snowman The solution (and the full problem) is also for other people that might have a similar problem. You have the opportunity to save them some time doing more research!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because of the bundling logic applied in webpack configuration.

Solutions:

1. You can use CDN, to solve the issue
   Add this in public/index.html file inside the head tag.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/2.14.1/react-datepicker.min.css" />`

Incase that doesn't help, you can check this link:
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/879

2. You can import it in src/index.js file instead of the current file

Comment: You are my hero.